# SQL insert query that uses number from auto_incremented column as insert value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

Essentially I have the following SQL query that inserts the three values into the three columns specified.

```
"INSERT INTO Equipment (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES ('TestInsertF1', 'TestInsertF2', 'TestInsertF3')";
```

The table also has an auto-incrementing ID column that creates a new ID every time the query above is executed.

How can I insert a value into `field4` where the value is hardcoded to be `"NUM: (The auto-incremented ID )"`

Answer (score 0):

I you are doing this in one transaction, probably the simplest method is to update *after* the insert.  In MySQL, this looks like:

```
INSERT INTO Equipment (field1, field2, field3)
    VALUES ('TestInsertF1', 'TestInsertF2', 'TestInsertF3');

UPDATE Equipment
    SET field4 = CONCAT('NUM: ', <id>)
    ORDER BY <id> DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Of course, this may not work if there are concurrent transactions.  For that, you would want to capture the most inserted id:

```
INSERT INTO Equipment (field1, field2, field3)
    VALUES ('TestInsertF1', 'TestInsertF2', 'TestInsertF3');

SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

UPDATE Equipment
    SET field4 = CONCAT('NUM: ', <id>)
    WHERE <id> = @id;
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to properly format this in PHP?